# Evolution Contact Sync failure in Ubuntu One

Tags: 10.04, evolution, ubuntu-one, sync, contacts

When do you plan to add Evolution contact sync on Ubuntu 10.04?

I know that it is working on Ubuntu 10.10 but there are ppl out there who do not like to upgrade to every new (and experimental, more or less) OS. Ubuntu 10.04 is a LTS version and it is strange that it takes so long to implement this feature. Many potential canonical customers would prefer to use this version, but buying ubuntuone without being able to sync contacts is annoying.

Comment: this more of a rant than a question...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I wasn't able to find a timeline for *when* there is an [explanation of why it isn't available on the 9.10 and 10.04 release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuOne/Status#Contacts).

> Syncing of contacts and bookmarks is
>   working for Ubuntu 10.10 (Maverick)
>   users. Maverick users will need to
>   have the latest updates installed.
>   Ubuntu 9.10 (Karmic) and Ubuntu 10.04
>   LTS (Lucid) users will have to wait a
>   bit longer for backporting of the
>   CouchDB and Erlang packages. We
>   presented the case for backporting
>   CouchDB to Ubuntu 10.04 LTS to the
>   Ubuntu Technical Board and the
>   suggestion was to investigate creating
>   a separate, special package that will
>   allow Ubuntu One databases (contacts,
>   bookmarks, etc.) to synchronize once
>   again. We're currently looking into
>   this.

Answer (score 2):

Until we get CouchDB 1.0 into Lucid (which we aim to do by the next point release), unfortunately replication won't work.

If you're feeling adventurous, you can try the PPA mentioned in
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Testing/CouchDBSRU; If you do, take care, and report any issues on that wiki page. Otherwise, please wait a couple more months. Thank you.